# UISearchDisplayController search bar position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Something has gone terribly wrong... All I have done, is setup a storyboard in Xcode, added a `UINavigationController` and set a root `UIViewController`, all of this is in a tab within tab bar controller.

I have added a `UISearchDisplayController` to the view in the storyboard, and am trying to position the search bar within the navigation bar using the following code in my view controller:

```
[self.searchDisplayController setDisplaysSearchBarInNavigationBar:YES];
```

This all works fine and i get the following:

[image]

However, when I tap into the search bar to enter content, it goes bezerk and centers itself in the middle of the view like this:

[image]

When I tap out of the search bar, it retains its crazy position in the middle of the screen like so...

[image]

What is going on here?

Comment: I suspect that this behaviour is because you added these `UIControls` in a `UIViewController` template in the storyboard. If instead you add to a `UITableViewController`, is the behaviour different? Also, apart from being able to search "something", what are you attempting to achieve in your view controller?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I discovered this the other day... The solution is to add the `UISearchBar` to the header view of a `UITableView` and then just hide the table view. The end result is a `UISearchBar` in the nav bar, but with an `MKMapView` as the main view of the controller.

Comment: Knowing what you are attempting to achieve, you should be able to use a `UIViewController` and embed a `UISearchBar` into the `UINavigationController`, however I suspect you would need to manage the location of the search bar for each phase of the view controller's lifecycle.